# How to filter out an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, substring

I'm trying to filter an array of objects where a certain key in the object contains an array of strings. Here's an example of the data structure.

```
let array = [{
  tags: ["this is a tag"]
}, 
{
  tags: ["this is not a tag"]
}]
```

I need to filter this array based on certain criteria. Here's what I've started with.

```
const filtered = array.filter(entry => entry["tags"].includes("n"))
```

This doesn't return anything but the following does.

```
const filtered = array.filter(entry => entry["tags"].includes("this is a tag"))
```

This returns the first entry because the entirety of the string matches. What I want is for comparisons between partial strings instead of the whole string but I can't seem to get anything to work. Does anyone know how to compare string arrays such that the first example would return the second entry?

Comment: `entry["tags"].includes("n")` this is looking for an element `"n"` inside the `tags` array. you need to use `entry["tags"][0].includes("n")`, as tags is an array, and `array.includes` is what's happening right now

Comment: `entry["tags"]` is an array. `includes` checks if the array contains a certain entry. If you want to filter for strings in that array that _contain_  a certain letter, you need the search to be a little deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `includes` is checking if the array `["this is a tag"]` contains the string `"n"`, which it clearly doesn't.

If you're looking to check if an array contains a string containing a specific letter, you need to do a deeper search:

```js
let array = [{
  tags: ["this is a tag"]
}, {
  tags: ["this is not a tag"]
}];

const filtered = array.filter(entry => entry.tags.some(tag => tag.includes("n")))

console.log(filtered);
```

Also note how I replaced the `entry["tags"]` with `entry.tags`. Bracket access isn't necessary there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string in a regex and match it against the `tags` array.

```js
let array=[{tags:["this is a tag"]},{tags:["this is not a tag"]}];

function check(arr, str) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`${str}`);
  return arr.filter(({ tags }) => {
    return tags[0].match(regex);
  });
}

console.log(check(array, 'this'));
console.log(check(array, 'n'));
console.log(check(array, 'targ'));
```

Comment: Why would you use an regex over `includes`?

Comment: Seemed more efficient. I can often be wrong.

Comment: I haven't benchmarked it, but I doubt regex with all its extra functionality is faster than `includes`, especially considering the interpreter knows exactly what to expect from `includes`, and a regex could do, well, anything :D

Comment: By "efficient" I didn't mean programmatically. I meant how my brain is working this morning :)

Comment: Ah, the coffee deficit :D